# BeginReceive in a separate thread

Tags: .net, sockets, asynchronous

For some reason, I need to do BeginReceive on a separate thread, much like this example :

```
    public void WaitForData()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(WaitForDataThread);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void WaitForDataThread()
    {
        try
        {
            CSocketPacket theSocPkt = new CSocketPacket();
            theSocPkt.thisSocket = m_socClient;
            m_asynResult = m_socClient.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnDataReceived, theSocPkt);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
```

But I've always received error right after the BeginReceive call, the OnDataReceived is instantly raised, in that event it will call the EndReceive method, and this error is always thrown : "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request".

But if I remove the separate-thread part (like directly call the WaitForDataThread(), without going through the WaitForData() method), everything works fine.

If you are wondering why would I need to create a separate thread, it is because I need to call the BeginReceive during an event that will be generated from a different thread from a different class. This is pretty much the same like creating a new thread like the sample above, and I need to make it work.

Is there a way that I can do this??

Comment: I really don't understand why you have to create a new thread to start an asynchronous operation?

Comment: I need to simulate the different thread event from other classes, so creating a new thread and calling the BeginReceive is the same like calling it in an event generated from a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b.aspx) (documentation of Socket.EndReceive):

> All I/O initiated by a given thread is
>   canceled when that thread exits. A
>   pending asynchronous operation can
>   fail if the thread exits before the
>   operation completes.

You have to make sure, that your thread where you start your socket-operation does not exit until you are done with your socket I/O.

A workaround is to use a threadpool thread, as described [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/608674-threadpool-vs-thread).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your main thread doesn't wait till the data comes, and simply exits after spawning the other thread. Finishing the main thread kills the whole application, so your WaitForData-thread dies, too.

You have to do the following:

1. Start the WaitForData-thread
2. Do whatever you want in Main thread
3. Wait until the WaitForData-thread finishes in Main thread (Thread.Join?)
4. Then exit.

Comment: Hi, this is not a Console application, this is a Winforms application. is this makes any difference?

Comment: Well, it makes some difference. The basic rule stays unchanged: you need to ensure that the main thread doesn't exit until your WaitForData thread is finished. Are you sure that you open a window at all?

Comment: Yes, the window is still opened, and the application is still running. Is there a way to call the BeginReceive from its original thread? I assume I would have to keep some loop going to preserve the original thread...